# keyUp and Keydown on jquery not firing while ajax code is

Tags: jquery, ajax

Keyup and Down are not firing.

`viewmenu` will change the content depends on the select menu. its works fine. but the `formsearch` is not working anymore. 
 `$(document).ready(function()` is in the main file. I just embedded the js.js and it seems it wont run the `document ready script`

Here's my code:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="asset/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="asset/js.js"></script>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
    var doneTypingInterval = 2000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example

    $('#formsearch').find(':input').each(function(){
          $(this).keyup(function(){
            typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
        });
    })
});
```

Js.js contains:

```
viewMenu = function(v){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'index.php?task='+v,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#display').html('LOADING...');
        },
        success: function(d){
            $('#display').html(d);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In what way are they "not working"?

Comment: Why use .each() why not bind it directly to the element?

Comment: What are they supposed to do? What's in `doneTyping`, and what does `viewMenu` have to do with this? Are there errors in console?

Comment: I think you don't need the ":" in the find(':input') part, like this: .find('input')

Comment: @JonasGrumann http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: Its not firing. `viewMenu` is working. but the keyDown and Ups are not. Edited the question

Comment: OT: @Juhana, thanks, I see. But I was wondering, what is the point of using :input when just 'input' will also select all the inputs (and I think it'll be faster)

Comment: @JonasGrumann `input` selects *only* `<input>`. `:input` selects inputs, textareas, select droprowns, buttons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you updated your content in the form via ajax.

You should bind event likes code below, because your DOM is changed when new content is added. That will cleared the event you bind before DOM changed.

```
$('#formsearch').on('keyup', ':input', function(){
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind it to the closest parent static element for dynamic content like this :

```
$('#formsearch').on('keyup',':input',function(){
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});
```